# Extract a specific word from a list

Tags: python, list

This is the output of my code and I want to extract the `Tap` word and store it separately.

```
[([[30.958056932529217, 1027.1867537178289],
   [78.85797763365605, 1035.0878794786204],
   [74.04194306747078, 1059.8132462821711],
   [26.14202236634395, 1051.9121205213796]],
   'Tap',
   0.985036313533783)]
```

Comment: What is its data type? Is it a list or a numpy array? Do you wish to get all the strings from the list or only `'tap'`?

Comment: I know we always ask for the minimal details for a problem, but perhaps you could give a little more setup. What is the tap portion of this?

Comment: That is element `[0][1]`.

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove it from the above list and just add it to another list? Or just check if its present? The question could do with a little more context. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The data type is a list. Additionally, I have attempted to extract text from an image and have got the output that I have shared. The first few numbers are the coordinates of where the text is located, the second part is the text and the third and final part is the confidence with which the text is generated.

Comment: Remember that you are using a tuple in a list. Also, what language is this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```py
data=[([[30.958056932529217, 1027.1867537178289],
   [78.85797763365605, 1035.0878794786204],
   [74.04194306747078, 1059.8132462821711],
   [26.14202236634395, 1051.9121205213796]],
   'Tap',
   0.985036313533783)]

for i in data:
    if i[1] == 'Tap':
        print(i[1])
```